# c# generic method + reflection question

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

In C# I want to create a generic method that:

1. Accepts a MethodInfo object as a parameter.
2. Returns the object that is returned when the MethodInfo is invoked.

The source of my confusion is that I want the method to be generically typed to the same return type as the MethodInfo object that gets passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this. By definition, generics are a compile-time construct, while the return type of a particular `MethodInfo` is something that is only known at runtime (when you receive a specific `MethodInfo` instance), and will change from call to call.

Comment: I don't know if just saying it's impossible is fair. You could for example create a wrapper MethodInfo<T> that guarantees it returns an object of Type T, and still benefit from compile-time generics as a result (so long as your use case could at least ensure you knew T at compile time).

Comment: The question requests that the method takes an instance of `MethodInfo`, not of some other type. Which does makes sense, since `MethodInfo` is what you get back from Reflection. Sure, if you actually know the type that it's going to return at compile-time, you can wrap it with a cast, but that defeats the purpose of doing all this in the first place.

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble envisioning a scenario where you want to do this and don't know the return type at compile time - if you don't then there is no benefit to generics in the first place. If you do then there are use cases in for example scanning an assembly for methods that match a certain format (including return type) and aggregating them as MethodInfo objects, for example as part of a templating library etc.

Answer (score 1):

Pavel Minaev is right,

My suggestion in this case (of course i don't know the whole context) is use a method that returns a dynamic type, of course is that wouldn't be typed.

```
public dynamic MyMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo)
```

Or since you know what is the return type, put that in the method call:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(MethodInfo methodInfo)
```

of course you gonna get in trouble inside the method mapping the conversions.
but you can also put the conversion in a parameter using lambda, like:

```
public T MyMethod<T>(MethodInfo methodInfo, Func<object, T> conversion)
```

i think the call of the method will be very clear, like:

```
Console.WriteLine(MyMethod(methodInfo, (a) => Convert.ToString(a)));
```